# Display hidden files command

Tags: unix

Hey fellas i have this command here `ls -la | egrep '^-' | egrep '^([^ ]+[ ]+){8}[.]' | wc -l` which diplays the number of hidden documents in the cwd.

- 1st qustion Why the above command has the same output with the `ls -la | egrep '^-' | tr -s ' ' |  egrep '^([^ ]+[ ]+){8}[.]' | wc -l`   I mean, the deletion of multiple spaces how can be done without writing the appropriate command?
- Also I dont understand 100% the action of the second egrep, someone explain me the seperation it does please.

Answer (score 2):

Let's take them one by one.

1. The `ls -la` prints out all files (including hidden) and lists them 
   with additional information, as the users rights, space & last modification.
2. The first `egrep` specifies that it will print only files, not
   directories, because it says to show all starting with "-", these
   that start with this symbol are files.
3. The `tr` is used in order to replace all the instances of repeated
   characters with a  single character, in this case a space.
4. As for the last `egrep` what it does is to match the hidden files and
   directories and print how many similar lines are found, which actually  means the number of the occurences, so how many times it found the same names for the directories and files (for the current directory that you are
   on, of course).

Answer (score 1):

1. tr -s ' ':-

   It only suppress the space.

   The ls -la list all the file and directories and file as line by line.

   So there is no change made in the output, because, the tr command does not suppress any new line.

2.

In starting, the input line does contains any characters other than space, after that it contains one or more space, this is in group. so like this 8 groups have to there after that the .(dot) is needed.

Example:-

The egrep matches the following lines.

```
drwxxr---x 1 sureshkumar sureshkumar  4096 May 12 10:21 .
drwxxr---x 1 sureshkumar sureshkumar  4096 May 12 10:21 ..
```

The following lines are not matched.

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sureshkumar sureshkumar  6361 May 12 17:30 1.c
-rwxrwxr-x 1 sureshkumar sureshkumar 12093 May 12 17:30 a.out
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sureshkumar sureshkumar     0 May 12 17:30 a.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 sureshkumar sureshkumar 34326 May 12 10:58 ping.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 sureshkumar sureshkumar 24951 May 12 15:48 ping_common.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 sureshkumar sureshkumar  8002 May 11 17:26 ping_common.h
```

Simply the egrep matches the hidden files and directories.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to count hidden files, in some senarios.

```
echo .*|wc -w
```

Note: Only if file names have no special char (whitespace, newlines) on them.

[Bash special char ref](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/special-chars.html)